# what's the derivative of $\cos(x) \sin(x)$

Tags: derivatives

before I ask for anything I must admit I'm working hard to understand this beautiful subject. Thanks in advance.
I want to get a derivative of: $\cos(x)\sin(x)$
The solution is the following:

$$ \frac d{dx}(\cos(x) \sin(x)) = \cos(2 x)$$

Where should I start?

Comment: Do you know the product rule? $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} (f(x) g(x)) = f(x) \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} g(x) + g(x) \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} f(x)$.

Comment: Of course, but I did not get a cos(2x) Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to recall the identity $\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos x$, which can be rewritten as
$$\sin x\cos x=\frac{1}{2}\sin 2x.$$
Now differentiate, not forgetting to use the Chain Rule.

An alternative is to differentiate $\cos x\sin x$ immediately, using the Product Rule. We get $(\cos x)(\cos x)+(-\sin x)(\sin x)=\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x$. Then recall the identity $\cos 2x=\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x$.

Comment: I did not know $cos(2x) = cosx^2 - senx^2$ identity. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you know $\cos 2x=2\cos^2 x-1$. The right-hand side is $\cos^2 x+\cos^2 x-1$. Replace one of the $\cos^2 x$ by $1-\sin^2 x$.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know the rules for taking the derivatives of products?

$$\frac d{dx}(uv) = u'v + uv'$$

Set
$u = \cos(x)$
and
$v = \sin(x)$ and find their derivatives using this rule.

Then you will need to use a [Double-Angle Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html) to get your desired result.